# Adding a link to another Sharepoint site in the saveas dialog

Tags: 2013

Is there a way (i.e. by implementing a app) that makes it possible for our company to browse to https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/projects while our default saveas location is always https://contoso.sharepoint.com

In that default location all of our document libraries from our main site  are visible. However it is not possible to navigate to our other site (by using mouse clicks only)

Comment: Could you please explain why it is not possible to navigate to other site? A screenshot would be best.